# How to have a radio button selected by default using leaflet.js' layers control?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

For my project I'm working with leaflet.js to display map and different layers on this map and I use radio button to select the desired layers. For this I use this code :

```
var WMS = {
    "<span id='bc' class='couches'>Bassin</span>": bc_l,
    "<span id='city' class='couches'>Commune</span>":city_l,
    "<span id='plot' class='couches'>Parcelles</span>":rdt_l
};

L.control.layers(WMS, null, {collapsed: false}).addTo(mymap);
```

And I would like to know how to have a radio button selected by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state of the radio buttons and the checkboxes in a [`L.Control.Layers`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#control-layers) is inferred from the layers present on the map.

Quoting from the [Leaflet tutorial on the layers control](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/):

> The layers control is smart enough to detect what layers we’ve already added [to the map] and have corresponding checkboxes and radioboxes set.
>
> Also note that when using multiple base layers, only one of them should be added to the map at instantiation, but all of them should be present in the base layers object when creating the layers control.

Therefore you can run something like `bc_l.addTo(map)` or `city_1.addTo(map)`, and the corresponding radio button will be set.